# How to handle an "undefined" error while converting CSV file to JSON using Papa Parse framework?

Tags: javascript, json, frameworks, google-chrome-devtools, papaparse

So, this is my JS code:

```
function main(){
    let myJSON = parseCSV();
    console.log(myJSON);
    let myCSV = transformCSV(myJSON);
    console.log(myCSV);
}

function parseCSV(){
    let parsedJSON;
    let selectedFile = document.getElementById('fileIn').files[0];
    Papa.parse(selectedFile, {
        complete: function(results) {
            parsedJSON = results.data;
            console.log(results.data);
            console.log(typeof(results.data));
        }
    });
    return parsedJSON;
}

function transformCSV(JSONIn){
    let csvOut = ""; // i will do something here later
    let dCol = ""; // i will do something here later
    let dRow = ""; // i will do something here later
    for (let i = 0; i < JSONIn.length - 1; i++) {
        // i will do something here later
    }
    return csvOut;
}
```

And this is my test html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src=".\transformCSV.js"></script>
    <script src=".\node_modules\papaparse\papaparse.js"></script>
    <input type="file" id="fileIn">
    <input type="button" value="click!" onclick="main()">
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to read length of `myJSON`, I get error message in Chrome console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. Why is it undefined? It is present in console! Why does this happen and how to fix it? How to work with resulted `myJSON` as a perfectly normal static JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the value of parsedJSON in the **complete** callback function. This will probably be called **AFTER** your function parseCSV has returned the undefined value of parsedJSON. You need to rewrite it with a callback or promise.

```
parseCSV(function (myJSON) {
  console.log(myJSON);
  let myCSV = transformCSV(myJSON);
  console.log(myCSV);
});

function parseCSV(callback){
  let parsedJSON;
  let selectedFile = document.getElementById('fileIn').files[0];
  Papa.parse(selectedFile, {
    complete: function(results) {
        parsedJSON = results.data;
        callback(parsedJSON);

    }
  });

}
```